# Parsing JSON response from API using DataFlow

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

How do I parse a JSON response from API as CSV?
Currently the API response is stored as a JSON file on Blob Storage and I now want to parse and save it as CSV file.

Here's a subset of the JSON response as sample,

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:dimension2",
          "ga:dimension1",
          "ga:dimension4",
          "ga:dimension6"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:newUsers",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "Australia",
              "Hong Kong",
              "HKNG",
              "not set"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "Australia",
              "Malaysia",
              "KL",
              "not set"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

the desired output.csv file should have column headers from the `data` key of JSON file.

```
the column header would ideally be like this,
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|dimension1 | dimension2 | dimension4 | dimension6 | metric_value|
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| Australia | Hong Kong  | HKNG       | not set    | 1           |
| ...       | ...        | ....       | ...        | ...         |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse a JSON response from an API and save it as a CSV file in Azure Data Factory (ADF) Data Flow, you can use the following steps:

- Take the Source transformation in dataflow and take the JSON file from Blob Storage as the source dataset.   Set the `documentForm` option to `arrayOfDocuments`. This will indicate that the JSON file contains an array of objects.

[image]

- Take the **Select transformation** and map the `data` field of the second object in the `reports` array to a new column called `data`.

`data = reports[1].data`

[image]

- Take the **Flatten transformation** and unroll the `values` array in the `metrics` field of the `data` column. Map the `dimensions` and `values` fields ato new  columns.
  [image]
- Then take the **Derive transformation**  to create new columns based on the `dimensions` and `values` columns. New columns called `dimensions2`, `dimensions1`, `dimensions4`, `dimensions6`, and `metric_values` are created here.

[image]

- Take the **Select transformation** is to select `dimensions2`, `dimensions1`, `dimensions4`, `dimensions6`, and `metric_values` fields only.
- Then take the sink transformation with csv dataset.

**Output:**

[image]

When the pipeline with this dataflow is run, the Json data will be copied to csv file in required format.

Comment: Thank you for putting in so much effort into answering it, really appreciate it!
But the JSON that I got as response from the API becomes unreadable (when view through 'Data preview' option and shows some Spark error, when I change the `Document form` from 'Document per line' to 'Single Document' or 'Array of Documents'. 

Any workaround that?

Comment: Do you get any error while using document form as doc per line